# iterate through perl object array

Tags: perl, selenium, moose

I have this object in perl

$elem = $driver->get_elements("//select[\@name[\"cars\"]//option");

```
<code><pre>
    1  Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x600f700)
      'driver' => Selenium::Remote::Driver=HASH(0x5bb9618)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
      'id' => 95
    2  Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x6012d18)
      'driver' => Selenium::Remote::Driver=HASH(0x5bb9618)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
      'id' => 96
    3  Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x5ff29f8)
      'driver' => Selenium::Remote::Driver=HASH(0x5bb9618)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
      'id' => 97
    4  Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x5ca26b8)
      'driver' => Selenium::Remote::Driver=HASH(0x5bb9618)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
      'id' => 98
    5  Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x600b330)
      'driver' => Selenium::Remote::Driver=HASH(0x5bb9618)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
      'id' => 99
```

Now I want to iterate through each Array Element in $elem.
How does one go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to dereference `$elem`, then loop:

```
for my $element (@{ $elem }) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Selenium::Remote::Driver` has no `get_elements` function, as far as I can see from the documentation. Instead, a [`find_elements`](https://metacpan.org/module/Selenium%3a%3aRemote%3a%3aDriver#find_elements) exists. It will return a flat array in list context, or an array reference in scalar context. That is, you can either do

```
my @elems = $driver->find_elements(...);
for my $elem (@elems) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
my $elems = $driver->find_elements(...)
for my $elem (@$elems) {
  ...
}
```

For further info on how to use references, read [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut).